# Site returns a dialog box, similar to a mime file save rather than excute a php file and return html

Tags: php, apache, wordpress, configuration

I've been running a wp 3.0 site and recently needed to update apache and php.  The upgrade went fine but some of the core wp functionality has been lost.

Now when I go into a post and attempt to use the media upload utility.  I can use the the file upload functions from the first 2 tabs but when I try to view the Gallery or the Library Firefox prompts to open or save the file, rather than returning the Gallery html.

I attempted the same thing in Chrome and ended up with a screen stating

```
No data received
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this web page later.
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.
```

I already checked the apache config file and the following is included in it.
Though not in that order they are all in the file at some location and were there previous to the upgrade.

```
LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache22/libphp5.so
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

I also checked the mime.types file to make sure there wasn't any mime-types in there and there wasn't.

If anyone has had this happen to them it would be a great assistance in letting me know what's going on.

Comment: If you save it, what are the contents?

Comment: And what is the URL? Is it `wp-admin/media.php` ?

Comment: When I save the file, it's completely empty, and the complete url is.  wp-admin/media-upload.php

Answer (score 0):

You should overwrite your corrupted core file with fresh ones, the only folder you shouldn't touch is /wp-content and do not overwrite your wp-config.php file.

Comment: just did a fresh upgrade from 3.0 to 3.2 with no change unfortunately.

Comment: So it means that wordpress probably isn't causing the problem. I would guess it is a file permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not so much an answer, as an explanation.  I'm running the site an older freebsd install and the root cause of the issue is the gd library used by php.  One of the function calls, imagetypes(), was causing an error that was not being logged anywhere and closing the Apache connection.

When the extension is removed the site worked fine.  So this particular situation is going to be fixed by updating freebsd and all apache/php libraries.